# How to capture native OSX audio data?

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

I'm using XCode/Objective-C to create a hardware LED music visualizer that lights up according to system audio.

Right now I am using SoundFlower to reroute the system sound card input into `AVRecorder`, but I am unable to capture individual buffer channels, and other users will have to install SoundFlower.

Is there another way (a framework, preferably) to accomplish this without using SoundFlower?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Jack framework](http://jackaudio.org) instead.
Here is a [tutorial on installing and routing the jack driver](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/advanced-audio-capture-mac-os-x.142/).

Comment: The jack framework seems like overkill for capturing the audio data of the system output and still requires separate installation. Thanks for the input, but I'm looking along the lines of a low-level C++ library or something like that.